# How to cross-compile a Chromium Embedded Framework (CEF) Windows app on Linux using MinGW

Tags: cmake, cross-compiling, chromium-embedded, mingw-w64

I'm trying to compile the cefclient and cefsimple applications provided in the [CEF3 distribution](https://cefbuilds.com/) into Windows executables from my Linux machine.

I'm running Linux Mint 17 (64-bit), and I'm trying to compile the Windows 32-bit versions of cefclient and cefsimple from [Branch 2454](https://cefbuilds.com/#branch_2454).

I have cmake and the MinGW cross-compilers installed, and I tested each individually. They all work well. I also have the build-essential, libgtk2.0-dev, and libgtkglext1-dev dependencies installed.

When I try to build the MakeFiles from a new `CEF/build` directory, I get an error:

---

**Command:**

`> cmake -G "Unix Makefiles" -D CMAKE_C_COMPILER=i686-w64-mingw32-gcc -D CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=i686-w64-mingw32-g++ ..`

**CMakeError.log**

```
Determining if the C compiler works failed with the following output:

Change Dir: /path/to/CEF/Source/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:/usr/bin/make "cmTryCompileExec1497229498/fast"

/usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec1497229498.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec1497229498.dir/build

make[1]: Entering directory '/path/to/CEF/Source/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'

/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_progress_report /path/to/CEF/Source/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/CMakeFiles 1

Building C object 

CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec1497229498.dir/testCCompiler.c.o

/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-gcc    -o 
CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec1497229498.dir/testCCompiler.c.o   -c     /path/to/CEF/Source/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c

Linking C executable cmTryCompileExec1497229498

/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec1497229498.dir/link.txt --verbose=1

/usr/bin/i686-w64-mingw32-gcc       CMakeFiles/cmTryCompileExec1497229498.dir/testCCompiler.c.o  -o cmTryCompileExec1497229498 -rdynamic

i686-w64-mingw32-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-rdynamic'

make[1]: *** [cmTryCompileExec1497229498] Error 1

make[1]: Leaving directory `/path/to/CEF/Source/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'

make: *** [cmTryCompileExec1497229498/fast] Error 2
```

---

This is my first attempt to cross-compile anything from Linux to Windows. Am I doing it wrong? Is there something I'm missing? What is the error message indicating?

Comment: For cross-compiling using CMake you need [toolchain file](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake-toolchains.7.html#id6), which, aside from compiler, defines also target name(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME).

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Tsyvarev! It worked. Sort of... I created a [toolchain file](https://gist.github.com/ttmarek/33ad9486d81169e877b6) which made the first error go away. It created [this output](https://gist.github.com/ttmarek/f83b9e6dd224fc5b19e6), and successfully created the MakeFiles. But, when running `make` on those makefiles, I get another error: [error from running make](https://gist.github.com/ttmarek/f62b0ae708b2e7f96972). I can't make heads or tails of it...

Comment: Top-level `CMakeLists.txt` sets compiler flags according to the target OS (`CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME`). So, it sees "Windows", and set flags started with `/`. But cross-compiler is run on Linux, so it used `-` notation for options(and different set of flags). Probably, you cannot cross-compile given project. (For correct cross-compiling project should check `CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_NAME` for set flags to compiler).

Comment: @Tsyvarev. I think you're correct. I'll post an issue on the project's Bitbucket page. I'll probably have to update their CMakeLists.txt file myself for now.

Comment: Proposal to add cross-compilation support to CEF: https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/issues/1718/add-cross-compilation-support-to-cef